# pandas: sum values by date in different dolumn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
data1 month day

20    1     1

10    1     1

15    1     2

12    1     2

16    1     3

10    1     3

20    2     1

10    2     1

15    2     2

10    2     2

12    2     3

10    2     3
```

I want to find the sum of data for each day of each month and display the result as a dataframe similar to the following:

```
date sum_data1

1.1. 30

2.1. 27

3.1. 26

1.2. 30

2.2. 25

3.2. 22
```

The data set is quite big > 200,000 rows.

Comment: You can add two columns: day, month and then to group by them and to sum,
I can elaborate more in an answer if you would like

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: Just as @jezrael Answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because no column `year` first add it to `month` and `day`, pass to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df[['month','day']].assign(year=2022))

df = df.groupby(date.rename('date'))['data1'].sum().reset_index(name='sum_data1')
print (df)
        date  sum_data1
0 2022-01-01         30
1 2022-01-02         27
2 2022-01-03         26
3 2022-02-01         30
4 2022-02-02         25
5 2022-02-03         22
```

Comment: could I expand this, e.g. if I originally had columns data1 & data2? could I generate two new columns besides the date, named sum_data1 and sum_data2?

Comment: @licm - sure, use `df1 = df.groupby(date.rename('date'))[['data1', 'data2']].sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'data1': [20, 10, 15, 12, 16, 10, 20, 10, 15, 10, 12, 10],
    'month': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'day': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
})
df['date'] = df['month'].astype('string') + '.' + df['day'].astype('string')

df.groupby(['date']).sum()[['data1']].rename(columns={'data1':'sum_data1'})
```

```
    sum_data1
date    
1.1 30
1.2 27
1.3 26
2.1 30
2.2 25
2.3 22
```

After that, you can use reset_index() if needed...

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.groupby(['month', 'day']).sum().reset_index()
df['New'] = df.apply(lambda row:  float(f'{row.day}.{row.month}'), axis=1)
df
```

Output:

```
    month   day data1   New
0   1       1   30     1.1
1   1       2   27     2.1
2   1       3   26     3.1
3   2       1   30     1.2
4   2       2   25     2.2
5   2       3   22     3.2
```